# How do I order the row by the desc or asc if the column is avg,Sql

Tags: sql

Here is my code:

```
SELECT make, AVG(x)
FROM y  
GROUP BY make
ORDER BY AVG(x) DESC   <===== this is the part I'm stuck on
HAVING COUNT(x) > 0 
LIMIT 10
```

I'm trying to print out the top 10 x. I already set 10 as limit.

The problem I am having is  the order part. Whenever I use `order by avg(x)`, it doesn't work. Can anyone explain why and offer a solution?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: put order by after having clause.

Comment: Yep, `HAVING` goes first, `ORDER BY` goes later.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is rarely a good problem description. If you're getting unexpected results, explain *what results you were expecting*. If you're getting an error message, *tell us what error*.

Answer (score 1):

The ordering of the clauses in SQL is important.  In your case, the correct ordering is:

```
SELECT make, avg(x)
FROM y  
GROUP BY make
HAVING count(x) > 0 
ORDER BY avg(x) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

`HAVING` goes after `GROUP BY`.  `ORDER BY` goes after `HAVING`.

Note that you can also write the `ORDER BY` using column aliases:

```
SELECT make, avg(x) as average
FROM y  
GROUP BY make
HAVING count(x) > 0 
ORDER BY average DESC
LIMIT 10;
```